# fixed div only vertically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want fixed an div or image in left of html page, and when scroll y, image scroll, but when scroll x image not scroll or fixed in left, I use jquery.sticky-kit.js and jquery-scrolltofixed.js plugin but when page resize to small width (mobile size) scroll x that, note that my page not responsive.

Another note that a mootools plugin is that work well, but I want do this in jquery.

Mootools plugin is in this link: http://demo.rickyh.co.uk/css-position-x-and-position-y/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:#ccc;
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    var content =  $("#content");
    var windowWidth = $(window).width()

    content.css("top",-$(window).scrollTop() + 50) // 50 is initial top position

    // if the window width is smaller than 600px - scroll also x-asis
    if (windowWidth < 600) { 

        content.css("left",-$(window).scrollLeft() + 50) // 50 is initial left position

    } else  {

        content.css("left", "50px") // 50 is initial top position    

    }

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n4we5xma/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS [position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) property : horizontal fixed ,vertical relative

```
.scroll_fixed {
    position:absolute;
}
```

See a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/g9pd4hpn/1/)